# How do I use the memory adapter with ember-pouch and ember-cli?

Tags: ember.js, pouchdb

It looks like ember-pouch is only available via NPM now, but the ember-cli docs say to use bower?

I still see pouchdb.memory.js in the pouchdb module, but the pouchdb docs say to use the pouchdb-adapter-memory package

So, with an ember-cli app, how do I turn on the pouchdb memory adapter?

Comment: Hi, please check out my answer and let me know if it helps. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have used `Pouch-DB` earlier which is straight forward.

### Install and setup

```
ember install ember-pouch
```

For ember-data < 2.0:

```
ember install ember-pouch@3.2.2
```

For ember-cli < 1.13.0:

```
npm install ember-pouch@3.2.2 --save-dev
```

This provides

```
 import PouchDB from 'pouchdb'
 import {Model, Adapter, Serializer} from 'ember-pouch'
```

### EmberPouch Blueprints

**Adapter**

You can now create an adapter using ember-cli's blueprint functionality. Once you've installed ember-pouch into your ember-cli app you can run the following command to automatically generate an application adapter.

```
ember g pouch-adapter application
```

Please refer these links for more details:

- [GitHub Ember-Pouch repo](https://github.com/nolanlawson/ember-pouch)
- [Ember-pouch NPM package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-pouch)

Comment: This does not cover how to get the memory adapter to work though.

Comment: I don't think there is anything like that, you might be talking about [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pouchdb-adapter-memory), pouch-adapter should serve your purpose

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to make this work. It's not super clean but because I expect that I'll need to do something different once ember-pouch updates their version of pouchdb I might as well take the easy path.

I copied pouchdb.memory.js from node_modules/pouchdb/dist into my vendor folder, and then added an import in my ember-cli-build.js

```
  var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  var app = new EmberApp(defaults, {
    // Add options here
  });

  app.import('vendor/pouchdb.memory.js');
  return app.toTree();
};
```